# Fetching object source programmatically

Tags: postgresql

I need access to the **complete** source code of objects in order to automate certain tasks. For example: complete source of view is the view itself, it's rules, triggers, privileges...

By using different PostgreSQL tools like PgAdmin, pg_dump, psql, this can easily be fetched, but I need to be able to access it through a (sql/plpgsql) function call.

It's not too difficult to implement API looking like this: getFunctionSource, getTableSource, getFUnctionSource. However, it looks like this code would need a lot of maintenance along different versions of database.

Is there **officially maintained or well tested** extension, API, pg_dump wrapper or whatever I can use?

Comment: @Denis I'm already trying it. But instead of doing it from scratch, maybe there's other open source effort that I can contribute to. To contribute to your logic: "not to difficult" is not the same as "easy". Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `psql -E`, you'll see hidden queries that get run by Postgres to output data definitions.

A function's raw source, for instance, can be found by running `\df foo`, reading the query, and subsequently trying:

```
select prosrc from pg_proc where proname = 'foo'
```

`\sf foo` doesn't yield the relevant functions using that approach, but a cursory peek at the [docs on system information functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) (of which there are many) should suggest that it's just a wrapper around:

```
select pg_get_functiondef('foo'::regproc);
```

---

A few views to get you started, if you go the route of posting your stuff on github:

https://gist.github.com/ddebernardy/7893922

(You'll want to create a "system" schema before running the file using \i in psql.)

Comment: Good example. select pg_get_functiondef('foo'::regproc); will return function definition, but not "alter function set owner" and setting of privileges. If you execute "pg_dump --schema-only -t foo yourdb", you will get the **complete** source. When I say complete, I mean when you drop an object and execute it's source, the whole db source remains the same.

Comment: Ya. And if you run `\df+ foo` after running `psql -E`, you'll see the owner appear along with the query you need to get it… The system catalog and system information functions are the "officially maintained or well tested" way to do it: it's how psql does it; and how pg_dump does it; and how PGAdmin does it; and how [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org) does it; and…

Comment: Can you use \df+ foo in plpgsql code? For example, can you create a plpgsql function that loops through all the views in a database and concatenate them and return them as text? As I recall, \df and other are psql meta-commands. Oh, and I already know how to "get the code that gets the code" manually. That is NOT what I need.

Comment: Then again, as much as it's NOT what you need, I'm afraid this probably IS what you'll use. There's no other officially maintained and well tested way to do it. `\df` aren't so much meta-commands as they're command batches that run queries on the `pg_catalog` for you. The easiest way to quickly become familiar with what these queries are and to fine-tune them per your own requirements is to show hidden queries by using `psql -E`. This gives you a starting point to tweak. The harder way is to query the catalog directly: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html

Comment: There also are the queries in the information schema, by the way. But they're usually less useful than the catalog imho: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html

Comment: Trouble is I can't use meta-commands (It's what they are called in the official psql docs). For my use case it is only useful as a help tool in building my own api, when I write the pg_catalog queries. 
This really makes me wonder: Why did PostgreSQL wrap it in meta-commands and pg_dump, but left sys functions so elementary. Sure, one can program an equivalent of meta-command in any stored procedure language available, but that seems to me like code duplication. Also, for every new version you have to go through relase notes and maintain the code.

Comment: "Why did PostgreSQL wrap it in meta-commands and pg_dump, but left sys functions so elementary." — If http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo is anything to go by, the main reason is there simply isn't any interest. In FOSS parlance, that usually means core devs are waiting for a volunteer to massage source files such as https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/psql/describe.c into something that exposes more useful APIs.

Comment: See these two threads on this particular topic. This one on `\d`: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3FFE532C.2090503@idigx.com and this other one on a bug in pg_get_indexdef(): http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/476975BF.9090009@postgresql.org

Comment: When I got interested in this topic, I browsed the PgAdmin code, and that's where I (correctly?) realized that they implemented source code generation for every object from scratch! Currently, my train of thought goes in the direction of implementing plpgsql api and putting it on github. This I can do and if I get no better answer in this thread, will do. The other option is exploring the possibility of reusing some of the psql and pg_dump code and exposing it as pg extension. Although I have some C experience, I would probably not get very far short-term.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a gist to get you started if you move forward with your github project. (They were written in 2011, but they'll probably still work as is.)